# How to make parameters available to SageMaker Tensorflow Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I'm looking to make some hyper parameters available to the serving endpoint in SageMaker. The training instances is given access to input parameters using hyperparameters in:

```
estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='autocat.py',
                       role=role,
                       output_path=params['output_path'],
                       code_location=params['code_location'],
                       train_instance_count=1,
                       train_instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge',
                       training_steps=10000,
                       evaluation_steps=None,
                       hyperparameters=params)
```

However, when the endpoint is deployed, there is no way to pass in parameters that are used to control the data processing in the `input_fn(serialized_input, content_type)` function.

What would be the best way to pass parameters to the serving instance?? Is the `source_dir` parameter defined in the `sagemaker.tensorflow.TensorFlow` class copied to the serving instance? If so, I could use a config.yml or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah i have had a similar problem to you where I needed to download something off S3 to use in the input_fn for inference. In my case it was a dictionary.

Three options:

1. use your config.yml approach, and download and import the s3 file from within your entrypoint file before any function declarations. This would make it available to the input_fn
2. Keep using the hyperparameter approach, download and import the vectorizer in `serving_input_fn` and make it available via a global variable so that `input_fn` has access to it.
3. Download the file from s3 before training and include it in the source_dir directly.

Option 3 would only work if you didnt need to make changes to the vectorizer seperately after initial training.

Whatever you do, don't download the file directly in input_fn. I made that mistake and the performance is terrible as each invoking of the endpoint would result in the s3 file being downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The Hyper-parameters are used in the training phase to allow you to tune (Hyper-Parameters Optimization - HPO) your model. Once you have a trained model, these hyper-parameters are not needed for inference.

When you want to pass features to the serving instances you usually do that in the BODY of each request to the invoke-endpoint API call (for example see here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/tf-example1-invoke.html) or the call to the predict wrapper in the SageMaker python SDK (https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/tree/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow). You can see such examples in the sample notebooks (https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/tensorflow_iris_byom/tensorflow_BYOM_iris.ipynb)

Comment: I want to pass in the S3 location of a vectorizer that is needed to turn text data into numerical features. Not the features themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one option is to add your configuration file to `source_dir` and load the file in the `input_fn`.

Another option is to use [`serving_input_fn(hyperparameters)`](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk#creating-a-serving_input_fn). That function transforms the TensorFlow model in a TensorFlow serving model. For example:

```
def serving_input_fn(hyperparameters):

    # gets the input shape from the hyperparameters
    shape = hyperparameters.get('input_shape', [1, 7])

    tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=shape)
    # returns the ServingInputReceiver object.

    return build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn({INPUT_TENSOR_NAME: tensor})()
```

[tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) [amazon-sagemaker](/questions/tagged/amazon-sagemaker) [hyperparameters](/questions/tagged/hyperparameters) [tensorflow-serving](/questions/tagged/tensorflow-serving)

Comment: The performance of loading and subsequently downloading a file in the input_fn is terrible as it would be done every time the endpoint is invoked.